# Bash usage section notations

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

What do brackets notation and ... mean in bash?

```
ls [OPTION]... [FILE]...
```

I would like to see if there is any documentation about this topic

Comment: This might help https://askubuntu.com/questions/787691/meaning-of-curly-braces-in-manpages

Comment: Best link from that link - [man page notations](http://www.tfug.org/helpdesk/general/man.html).